# Understanding AWS EC2 Cluster Usage

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a Question about The Cluster usage in AWS. If I have 10 Instances running, do I have One master Instance and when I run a threaded Application on One Instance, is the application able to use all Instances like it would with multiple Cores?

I have seen the Tutorials on the Website but I can't figure out how these Clusters work. If I run One Application it counts as one job even if threaded right? So will only one instance be used?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In aws , you have one master instance and one to many core instances.
Master instance will schedule and lead the job but the core ones will do all the work.
There is also an option of task instances which will process when it comes to tasks.

Cheers,